# Redirecting url with parameter

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to redirect the url

> http://sitename.com/test/test

as

> http://sitename.com/test.jsp?name=test

I am having issues in passing paramenter while redirecting.
Can any one help me in this.
What can i do for getting this..

Comment: You say you're having issues, which suggests you've got some code... so please show us that code.

Comment: I have used the following in web.xml .`<servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>test.jsp</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: @ash, you can't call your servlet name `test.jsp`. That's against Servlet specification.

Comment: Where is the context root in your URL? Is it test?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your jsp or servlet

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
if (name != null && name != "") {
    response.sendRedirect("test/"+name);
}
```